# Get Type from a list element c#

Tags: c#, listbox, gettype

I have a C# ListBox filled with elements of class "Human".
Every element can be of a class that derived from Human such as "Old", "Young".
I want to know if the element selected in the ListBox is Old or not.
I try to use .GetType() but it gives me back the type "string" becouse is a list
element while i want the type "Old" or "Young".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`is`-expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
var query = myListBox.Items.Cast<Human>()
    .Select(h => new { IsOld = h is Old, IsYoung = h is Young, Human = h });
```

**Edit**:  *"I want to know if the element selected in the ListBox is Old or not"*

Then you don't need the LINQ query:

```
Human human = (Human) myListBox.SelectedItem;
bool isOld = human is Old;
```

Comment: There's no need to test beyond `IsOld` according to OP's requirements

Comment: He doesn't need to test these though. "I want to know if the element selected in the ListBox is Old or not". Anything more than Selman's answer seems a bit of overkill for that.

Comment: @DeeMac: ah ok, i've overlooked that he's only interested in old human. But i keep it as it is in case OP will change his mind.

Comment: Thanks!! Both answers are ok, but what i need is simply to know if is old or not. Anyhow Tim's solution doesn't compile but it's my code fault maybe.

Comment: @user3876331: what error do you get? Have you seen that i've edited my answer 20min ago? The first is a LINQ query where you need at least VS 2008.

Comment: The error is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.string' to type 'class.Human' where class is the name of my project. I'm using VS2010 and your second version (without LINQ)

Comment: If there are strings in the ListBox instead of instances of `Human` the accepted answer won't work either. It just swallows the bug since it returns `false`.

Comment: I add to the list Human elements, but when i do the .SelectedItem it gives me back a string. For example MyLstBox.SelectedItem.GetType().ToSTring() gives me back system.string.
I want only test if is Old or not

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

```
bool isOld = (listBox.SelectedItem as Old) != null;
```